# Could not find member 'Fade'

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm using swift to develop a table view based application. I'm trying to delete a row from the table view with row animation fade. A simple and straight forward thing to do, at least that's what I thought. Swift does not make a lot of things easy and it seem to be very convoluted (still need to be convinced if another programming language was necessary).

Im trying to delete a table row like so:

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPath, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

Which I don't see why this simple process should me anymore complicated than it is. (it puzzles me)

And Xcode6 (Beta) seems to complain although it is code provided by the automatic generating of the swift class. (Back to Objective-C please)

Error: `Could not find member 'Fade'`

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Does 'UITableView().deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(nil, withRowAnimation: .Fade)' work? It works here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't say why Xcode 6 is giving you that error, but there is *another* error in your call:

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPath, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

should be

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

As `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` expects and `AnyObject![]` array, not an `NSIndexPath` instance.

Maybe that's the problem and Xcode is getting it wrong for some reason?

Comment: I've tried that just now and keep getting a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: It probably is the cause of the problem. The `.Fade` shortcut works because Swift does type inference and figures out which enum it belongs to. But that depends on Swift knowing which method you want to call, and if you get the types (i.e. the signature) wrong, there is no such method and therefore, nothing can be inferred.

Comment: I understand that this is the case but when I try this out (I've started 2 new projects for this) I always get Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error not sure what in the world this means @Lukas

Comment: If you use the API methods to get the indexPath, like self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location) they return an optional, so you need to unwrap it, [indexPath!].

Answer (score 10):

I've been having the same problem.  The only way I got rid of the compiler error was to use ! on the two optionals, tableView and indexPath.

```
tableView!.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

Comment: In the screenshot the two parameters are not optionals. So i don't see why this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Not saying this should be the accepted answer, but if you use API methods to get the indexPath, like, self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location) they return an optional.  And the compiler warning is really not helpful.